# WPF: How to handle multi-XAML UIs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I don't know about you folks, but I suffer from a severe case of *Deep Indentation Allergy*. I can barely manage all those indented XAML blocks.

My current application is based on a large DataGrid with of kinds of fancy features (with more to come) but I would like to add a couple a tabs on top of the screen in order to have an additional, second very similar DataGrid.

I would like to implement it as follow:

```
<Tab>
    <Tab Selection 1>
        <DataGrid 1 in some other XAML file>
    </Tab Selection 1>
    <Tab Selection 2>
        <DataGrid 2 in some other XAML file>
    </Tab Selection 2>
<Tab>
```

So, I would have a small XAML file which controls 2 much bigger XAML files.

That should be doable, right?

Can a kind soul provide the details?

TIA.

Comment: I hope this is not an `XY Problem!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [create a new UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx#models_for_control_authoring):

**1** - Right Click your Project in Solution Explorer, select `Add` `->` `New Item`:

[image]

**2** - Select `WPF UserControl`:

[image]

**3**: Create your `DataGrid` inside the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <DataGrid>
      <!-- lots of XAML ... -->
   </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

**4**: Put the `UserControl` inside the `TabItem`:

You will need to [*Import your Namespace*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx), like so:

```
<Window ....
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">

    <TabControl>
      <TabItem>
         <local:MyUserControl/>
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```