# Please discuss the "WPF: How to handle multi-XAML UIs?" Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

This is a continuation of my thread:

[WPF: How to handle multi-XAML UIs? (Follow-Up)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444114/wpf-how-to-handle-multi-xaml-uis-follow-up)

I am curious as to the parent-child relationship between an `abc.xaml` file and its corresponding `abc.xaml.cs`. How is the relationship implemented? Why does one look under/inside the other in MSVS? How would I create those two files with Notepad? Is it simply a matter of naming them with a common basename?

TIA.

Comment: Do not post separate question.

Comment: @RohitVats despite the mention to other question, this is a separate question in itself about a completely different matter.

Comment: @HighCore is correct. In fact, I experimented with Notepad and the answer to `this.` (pun intended :-) post is: "Yes, the files are considered hierarchically linked basely solely on the fact that they share the basename". I wrote a couple minimal 2-liners (a `.xaml` and a `.xaml.cs` and MSVS seemed to be completely persuaded of their legitimacy. However, I have absolutely no clue about the related question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444114/wpf-how-to-handle-multi-xaml-uis-follow-up> which remins unanswered. Perhaps what I want is not possible?

Comment: @TravisBanger no the file names have nothing to do with anything. Please see my answer. A file is dependent upon other file in a .Net project if it's `ProjectItem` is marked as `[DependentUpon]` in the Project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about that too much if I were you. It's a completely IDE-related matter that does not really affect you in any way.

Yet, let me explain that to you real quick:

When you add a `UserControl` or `Window` in a WPF Project by using the Visual Studio `Add -> New Item..` action, Visual Studio adds 3 files to your project:

1 - `MyUserControl.xaml` Is the XAML file, which contains the XAML that comprises your UserControl.

2 - `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`, which is the "code behind" file, that defines a `public partial class` derived from `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`, which allows you to create additional logic for the interaction with your `UserControl`.

3 - Under the covers, another file called `MyUserControl.g.i.cs` is also generated. This file contains the same class as #2, also defined as `partial`, and additionally contains the definition of all the `fields` inside the class for any relevant XAML-defined elements that were given an [`x:Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This means that if your XAML contains something like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"/>
```

the `.g.i.cs` file will contain a declaration like this:

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.TextBox TextBox1;
```

the value of this field is assigned via WPF's internal mechanisms that I will not discuss right now.

The bottom line is that the code you may write in the `MyUserControl.xaml.cs` code behind file is probably going to make use of the class members defined in `.g.i.cs` (such as `TextBox1`), and since that file is dependent on the XAML file, so is your code behind file.

That's why the code behind file is set as [DependentUpon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) the XAML file in the [Project Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx), which if you look at the `csproj` file, looks something like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="MyUserControl.xaml">
       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyUserControl.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MyUserControl.xaml</DependentUpon>
        <!-- notice how this file is defined as DepedentUpon the XAML file -->
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

<!-- ... -->
```